# In SSMS, how can I safely copy the name of an object from object explorer?

Tags: ssms

Sometimes I want the name of an object copied to the clipboard. I usually hit F2 to rename and copy while the text is selected. This seems dangerous. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+C with the object highlighted. The schema and object name will be copied to the clipboard. No need to press F2!

```
[dbo].[objectname]
```